# Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch. - Should multiple dispatchers be used?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

https://gist.github.com/criso/086881ec8df844eda73a

Should these independent components be using different `dispatchers` ?

Scenario:
Compnonent `BAR` requests data from the server via an action `REQ_BAR`
Component `FOO` receives data from a previous request `REQ_FOO_SUCCESS`

`--- Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch. ---` error is triggered

### EDIT

Basically, if you have 2 components that retrieve data from the server:
- component `FOO` may be dispatching `REQ_FOO`
- while component `BAR` may be dispatching `REQ_BAR_SUCCESS`

Comment: You can overcome this by triggering   ActionCreators.requestFooDetails() within componentDidUpdate method as  componentDidUpdate is not called on the initial render.

I'm not sure what's the use case though

Comment: Who calls `requestFooDetailsSuccess`?

Comment: `fooApi` - on a response from the serveri, it'll call actionCreator.requestFooDetailsSuccess

Answer (score 1):

You can use `waitFor` in Flux. So you fire one `action` and have two `stores` that are register to the same dispatcher. But one waits for the other store to process the payload.

Check out the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html#content)

Comment: Actually looking more into it. I would have the `action` do the request to the server and based on the response fire another `action` that your store is registered to. `failAction` `successAction`

Comment: These stores aren't related. I don't need the data from one store to be used on the other store. Also, `waitfor` won't prevent the action from being dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this:
https://github.com/facebook/flux/issues/47#issuecomment-54716863
"An action queue would not be a bad solution if you have multiple async API calls coming back at the same time."

I don't see how you may not run into this at some point.